# Add Visual Studio Professional subscription to Azure account

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I need some help in activating my Azure MSDN subscription.

I had earlier created a free account with Organization ID which got expired after 1 month. After this, I did not do anything and this Azure subscription of mine is disabled.

Now, I have installed VS Professional licensed copy on my system for which I want to change the Azure Free subscription to Azure MSDN subscription.

But, when I try to add new subscription to my Azure account with VS Studio MSDN, it says -

> You are not eligible for this offer.
> This offer is only available to Visual Studio Professional Subscription (MSDN) subscribers.

Also, when I open "https://my.visualstudio.com", it still shows my subscription type as "Visual Studio Dev Essentials".

How to resolve this issue?

Any extra steps to be taken to associate my Organization ID with VS subscription?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with these steps

1.If you already have the subscription .If you assigned a subscription to yourself, you can visit the [Visual Studio subscriber portal](https://my.visualstudio.com/) to start downloading software and using other subscriber benefits.

2.Click **View my subscription** to open the subscriber portal and begin using
your subscription.

[image]

If you purchased more than one subscription, proceed to the [Visual Studio Subscriptions Admin portal](https://manage.visualstudio.com/) to assign subscriptions to others. You may need to [add your new subscriptions to the Admin Portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/subscriptions/add-monthly-subs) if this is the first time you've purchased them.

[image]

[image]
For more details refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/subscriptions/vscloud-overview)

Comment: Thanks! I need to connect with our admin to get this done.